# Laravel 5.4 - Query to get all posts placed by people the current user is following

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a Laravel API for my app. I was wondering how to build a query that gets all posts that are placed by people the current user is following. The models needed are:

Follows:

- id
- user_id
- follow_id

Posts:

- id
- Title
- Description
- user_id

The current user->id is given that's what I want to use to get the posts.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you want as output?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a Has - Many -Through relationship. Your User will pivot on the user's they are following to find all posts that belong to those users. See the documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through